# Getting error C2177: constant too big with MPIR

Tags: c++, biginteger, mpir

Running on Widows 7 with MSVS 2010

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.mrrives.com/Technology/?p=668) to understand how to use [MPIR library](http://www.mpir.org/) for adding two big integers

I understand this library should help me in adding very big numbers as shown in the program below:

```
#include < stdio.h>
#include < stdlib.h>
#include < gmpxx.h>
#include < iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   mpz_class answer_a = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111;
   mpz_class answer_b = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111;


   mpz_class answer_c; 

   answer_c= answer_b + answer_a ;   

   cout << answer_c<<"\n";


}
```

But still I get  `error C2177: constant too big`. 
Did I misunderstand [MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/) ?

Comment: I suggest tagging it as C++.

Comment: In `c`, don't `#include < iostream>`, if in `c++`, don't `#include <stdio.h>`, use `#include <cstdio>`. You decide.

Comment: so now you decide it to be C++ then why `#include <stdio.h>`? And [`void main()` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 4):

Such constant is (very likely) too big for standard integer types. You should use `char *` constructor instead:

```
void mpz_class::mpz_class (const char *s)
```

For example:

```
mpz_class answer_a("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
```

to make this work you need to include suitable MPIR C++ interface header (notice that `<gmpxx.h>` is from C++ interface of [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/) library):

`#include <mpirxx.h>`

See 12.2 C++ Interface Integers chapter in MPIR documentation for more details.

Comment: You beat me, I almost wrote the same answer :)

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski Thanks.  Tried this  but says: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [49]' to '__gmp_expr<mpz_t,mpz_t>'

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski  But where do I put   void mpz_class::mpz_class (const char *s)? I am reading the manual.

Comment: @user3891236: I found it, you need to include `<#include <mpirxx.h>` as well. Don't declare constructor by yourself, it should be always in header file.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Now it gives additional error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [49]' to '__gmp_expr<mpz_t,mpz_t>'  AND thsi error    
1>          Constructor for class '__gmp_expr<mpz_t,mpz_t>' is declared 'explicit'

Comment: @user3891236: Yes, I confirm that (on Visual Studio 2013 with version 2.7.0), you might report it to MPIR developers as a bug if you like. As a workaround declare `answer_a` without initializer (i.e. `mpz_class answer_a;`), then assign `answer_a = "111....";` in separate statement.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski The work around worked. But why?

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski Your code is using the `char *` *assignment operator*, not the `char *` *constructor* . In order to use that constructor, you'd have to write this code: `mpz_class answer_a("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");` (which, technically speaking, avoids a useless assignment)

Comment: @MihaiTodor: Of course you're right, fixed my answer to use proper form.